# Modify JSON object using JavaScript based on title search

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a ASP.Net hidden field which has data in JSON format as shown below

```
[
  {
    "RegionName": "USA",
    "Contact": {
      "LegalName": "somethinglegal",
      "StreetAddress": "hello",
      "City": "Test",
      "State": "Test",
      "Zip": "8888",
      "Country": "USA",
      "VAT": "VAT"
    },
    "EntityContact": {
      "LegalName": "Test",
      "Email": "Test@test.com",
      "Phone": "9998887777"
    }
  },
  {
    "RegionName": "Mexico",
    "Contact": {
      "LegalName": "somethinglegal",
      "StreetAddress": "hello",
      "City": "Test",
      "State": "Test",
      "Zip": "33333",
      "Country": "Mexico",
      "VAT": "VAT"
    },
    "EntityContact": {
      "LegalName": "Amex",
      "Email": "test@test.com",
      "Phone": "9998887777"
    }
  }  
]
```

which is read in Javascript using below code

```
var value = $('#countryInvoice')[0].defaultValue;
```

Now I want to search this JSON using javascript based on Region name and delete the record from the hidden field. So I want to remove the data point for say USA so only the below remains

```
[    
      {
        "RegionName": "Mexico",
        "Contact": {
          "LegalName": "somethinglegal",
          "StreetAddress": "hello",
          "City": "Test",
          "State": "Test",
          "Zip": "33333",
          "Country": "Mexico",
          "VAT": "VAT"
        },
        "EntityContact": {
          "LegalName": "Amex",
          "Email": "test@test.com",
          "Phone": "9998887777"
        }
      }  
    ]
```

Can someone please tell me how to do it in JQuery or Javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: `var result = yourArray.filter(function(o){ return o.RegionName === 'Mexico'; });` or `const result = yourArray.filter(o => o.regionName === 'Mexico');`. The later is less backward compatible.

Comment: @StackSlave - The filter condition should be `o.regionName !== "USA"`, not `o.regionName === 'Mexico'`. Your code ignores including other elements which aren't USA but also not Mexico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//ES5
var res = value.filter(function(e) { return e["RegionName"] != "USA"; })

//ES6
var res = value.filter(e => e["RegionName"] != "USA")
```

**Note:** The Arrow function is ES6 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to filter it out using `Array.prototype.filter()`.

Check out the MDN Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

The snippet below filters out USA

```js
let value = [{
    "RegionName": "USA",
    "Contact": {
      "LegalName": "somethinglegal",
      "StreetAddress": "hello",
      "City": "Test",
      "State": "Test",
      "Zip": "8888",
      "Country": "USA",
      "VAT": "VAT"
    },
    "EntityContact": {
      "LegalName": "Test",
      "Email": "Test@test.com",
      "Phone": "9998887777"
    }
  },
  {
    "RegionName": "Mexico",
    "Contact": {
      "LegalName": "somethinglegal",
      "StreetAddress": "hello",
      "City": "Test",
      "State": "Test",
      "Zip": "33333",
      "Country": "Mexico",
      "VAT": "VAT"
    },
    "EntityContact": {
      "LegalName": "Amex",
      "Email": "test@test.com",
      "Phone": "9998887777"
    }
  }
];

let newArray = value.filter(arr => arr.RegionName !== 'USA');
console.log(newArray);
```